# SQL Server : pagination into Excel

Tags: sql-server, pagination, recursive-query

I've got a large data set that I need to get into excel to get some pivot tables and analysis going.

I normally am able to do this as the data never reaches the 1 million line mark. I just do a SQL Server data import and specify my SQL statement.

Here is my current SQL

```
WITH n AS (
    Select A1.AccountID, A1.ParentAccountID, A1.Name
    FROM Account AS A1
    WHERE A1.ParentAccountID = 92
UNION ALL
    SELECT A2.AccountID, A2.ParentAccountID, A2.Name
    FROM Account AS A2
    JOIN n
    ON A2.ParentAccountID=n.AccountID
)
select n.*, D.DeviceID, A.*, P.*
FROM n
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    Device AS D
    ON D.AccountID = n.AccountID
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    Audit as A
    ON A.AccountID = n.AccountID
RIGHT OUTER JOIN
DeviceAudit As P
ON P.AuditID = A.AuditID
WHERE A.AuditDate > CAST('2013-03-11' AS DATETIME)
ORDER BY n.AccountID ASC, P.DeviceID ASC, A.AuditDate DESC
```

This right now is returning to me 100% of what I need. 18 million records for the past 30 days. I was hoping there would be a simple way to find the next 100,000 or 500,000 records.

I can use `TOP 100000` to get my first chunk, though I do not seem to have an offset available to me.

At present this runs and completes in 20 minutes. This is 1 of many account hierarchies that I have to perform this for. Hopefully this pagination will not be too expensive cpu wise.

I did try exporting to a CSV in hopes of importing it, though that just gives me a 12GB csv file that I do not have time to and break apart.

Comment: You found any answer? I have the same situation

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do paginated subqueries on the row number since SQL 2005. Add a row number to the select clause of your original query:

```
, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY {whatever id}) AS row
```

Then you can make your old query a subquery and query against the row:

```
SELECT TOP {results per page} *
FROM ({your previous sql statement})
WHERE row > {page# * results per page}
```